# Can you rearrange inequalities?

Tags: inequality

Based on the central limit theorem and the rules for the normal distribution,  we can get this equation:

[image]

I fully understand the first line of working. However, I am not sure if the second equation is correct.

I tried to split the inequalities into separate parts (x bar - 1.96*standard error < estimated mean) but was unable to get this inequality. How do I get it?

Source: https://sites.nicholas.duke.edu/statsreview/ci/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take the left inequality in the top equation:

$$\mu-1.96 \cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} < \bar{X}$$

Add the right term on the left side to both sides:

$$\mu < \bar{X} +1.96 \cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$$

This is now the right inequality in the bottom equation.

Do the same for the other one and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way of looking at it, for positive $\epsilon$ and any reals $a, b$: $$b-\epsilon < a < b+\epsilon \iff |a-b|< \epsilon \iff a-\epsilon < b < a+\epsilon$$